# Polygon misalignment with OpenLayers & Ordnance Survey data (possible projection issue)

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, openlayers, ordnance-survey

I'm trying to plot polygons on an OpenLayers map of Scotland which represent the area covered by UK Ordnance Survey maps. These polygons should cover the whole of Scotland and have no gaps between them. However when the polygons (with yellow edges) appear on the map they appear to be misaligned with slight gaps between some of them. The polygons should overlap in places (some locations appear on two maps) but there should be no gaps.

[image: misaligned polygons]

I've checked the co-ordinates (in both their original OS X & Y co-ordinate form and their converted latitudes and longitudes, done using PHPcoord http://www.jstott.me.uk/phpcoord/) and they seem to be accurate and fine. Which makes me think it might be a projection issue, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or how to change it.

I wasn't able to create a JSFiddle using my actual GeoJson file so the JSFiddle below shows my map code but with the GeoJson file missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndySweet/e4qrs42w/

I've validated the GeoJson file and it seems to be ok.

Comment: Without the geojson file we can not really help you. It is the key to identify your problem. Why dont you upload it somewhere? Or add just a part of it as a string variable within your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @pavlos. Here are the contents of the GeoJson file saved in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndySweet/2o8v1x1L/

Comment: The gaps come from coordinates. Here is a fiddle -->https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/proggazz/  click on any polygon to see its coordinates on an info box above map. If you check the original coords you should see that there is a gap. So better check your coords again.

Comment: Thanks @pavlos. It seems you're right, I used an online coordinate converter and thought they were accurate but they're not perfect. I tried another converter and they were also slightly out.

I have now gone back to my original data which is in the Ordnance Survey X and Y format (OSGB 36) as I know that is accurate. However now I do actually seem to have a projection issue and can't figure out how to fix it. The polygons are now aligned as they should be but placed over West Africa instead of Scotland. Here's a fiddle of the new map:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndySweet/47c1vr1v/

Comment: Do you know the projection code of your data????

Comment: Your projection code is 27700 you also need to include proj4js library within your app. You also need to add the projection info to the geojson string. Here is a fiddle to see your data --> https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/zhux0nL8/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @pavlos! I've been struggling with this for weeks and in previous versions of my code I had the proj4js library included and the CRS info but somehow I got confused and I lost them.

Comment: no probs my friend. Glad to help

Comment: Now I have another problem, correctly formatting my json file. I'm struggling to add the CRS information & my polygon field is being exported with double quotes around them. I think it's something to do with the array but can't quite figure it out.

This is what I'm using to create the json file: https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndySweet/urxs1o7e/ The data is pulled from a MySQL database & the polygon field is longtext in the format [195500,552000],[215500,552000], etc.

This fiddle compares what I'm getting from the json file with what I want to get: https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndySweet/rx2v2ot3/

Comment: You can just evaluate coordinates on client just before passing the geojson object to ol format. check the fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/z1qrfjdv/ to see how to evaluate

Comment: Thanks, but I think I must be implementing it wrongly. I don't fully understand what it's doing. In this fiddle I've done what I thought was correct but it doesn't show the polygons.

https://jsfiddle.net/MrAndySweet/azaa767b/1/

Also I'm not clear how to (eventually) load my json file url into the phpGeoJson variable instead of using the example text.